# Picking 3 random books probability problem

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, random

So the question is:
Suppose a bookcase holds 6 chemistry, 5 math, 3 physics, and 8 computer science texts.  if 3 books are selected, find the probability that none of the math texts are selected.

My attempt at this question is since there are 22 books total, we can just subtract 5 from the total and get 17 so 17/22 is the probability.  I do not believe this is right though because it just seems too easy.  What am i doing wrong, if i am doing it wrong?

Comment: Why subtract five and not six?

Comment: because there are 5 math books @Karl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some hints:

- What is the probability of not taking a math book?
- What is the probability of not taking a math book if one non-math book has been removed?
- What is the probability of not taking a math book if two non-math books have been removed?

The total probability is the product of these three probabilities.

Comment: so it would be 19/22 * 19/21 * 19/20? @John

Comment: so it would be 19/22 * 19/21 * 19/20? @John

Comment: No. There are $17$ non-math books out of $22$, so the first probability is $17/22.$ After one (non-math) book has been removed, there is one less non-math book *and* there is one less total book. If this doesn't make sense, get a sheet of paper, tear it up into $22$ pieces, and label them $C, M, P, CS$ in the appropriate numbers, and actually take one of the pieces of paper away, and count what's left.  (For this problem, remove one of the $CS$ pieces of paper, because it's not an $M$.)

Comment: ohh so its 17/22 * 16/21 * 15/20 then? @John

Comment: Yes, that's it!

Comment: ok thanks a lot @John

Answer (score 0):

6 Chemistry, 5 Math, 3 Physics, and 8 Computer books. Total 22 Books.

I looked at it using Hypergeometic Probability. $$P(X=x)={{N_1\choose x}{N_2\choose n-x}\over{N\choose n}}$$
Where our $N_1=5,N_2=17,N=22,n=3,x=0$
 $$P(X=0)={{5\choose 0}{17\choose 3}\over{22\choose 3}}={4\over17}$$